# iPhone is there a way to produce the .app file by using the command line?

Tags: iphone

I just upgraded my Xcode ide.  I have 3 logins.  In the logins I did not upgrade Xcode, the die will no longer build the app file no matter what I do.  I erased the file, did a clean, did build several times.

I was wondering if I could build the app file using the command line??????
Or does anybody know how to fix this issue???
Ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xcodebuild` command to build projects from the command line. It's not clear what your actual problem is, though, and if your project won't build it's unlikely that building using `xcodebuild` is going to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the command line and try `man xcodebuild`.  It should show you all the options.